# Encountering Race Conditions Despite Using Django's Atomic Transactions and select_for_update

Tags: python, django, postgresql, transactions, race-condition

I'm encountering race conditions in my Django application despite implementing atomic transactions and utilizing the select_for_update method. Here's an overview of the problem and the steps I've taken so far:

**Problem**:
I have two Django models, Transaction and Account, where Transaction instances affect the balance of associated Account instances. However, due to the large size of transactions, I'm experiencing race conditions, resulting in false outcomes and incorrect balance updates.

**Database Schema**:

```
Transaction:
    id (Primary Key)
    amount
    account_id (Foreign Key referencing Account.id)

Account:
    id (Primary Key)
    balance
```

**Steps Taken**

1. Atomic Transactions: I've wrapped the critical sections of my code that involve database operations within Django's atomic transactions using the `@transaction.atomic` decorator or transaction.atomic context manager.
2. Row-Level Locking: I've utilized the `select_for_update` method to lock the rows in the Account table during reads, ensuring that concurrent transactions don't interfere with each other's updates.

Despite implementing these measures, I'm still encountering race conditions, leading to incorrect balance calculations and data inconsistency.

**Additional Context**:

I'm using a PostgreSQL database for my Django application.
The race conditions seem to occur when multiple transactions attempt to update the balances of related accounts simultaneously.
I've verified that the critical sections of my code are indeed encapsulated within atomic transactions and that `select_for_update` is applied appropriately.

**Question**:
What additional steps or considerations should I take to mitigate race conditions in my Django application? Are there any common pitfalls or overlooked factors that might be contributing to this issue despite using atomic transactions and row-level locking? Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: None. Take a closer look: increase logging verbosity and catch it happening. Once you know what set of steps leads to invalid balance, reproduce those, line by line, inspecting query by query and see at which point it breaks. It's hard to advise based zero code, only a description. To throw some guesses around: maybe you're pooling connections the wrong way and even though you do lock stuff, your agents operating concurrently actually share the sessions/connections issuing the locks, therefore not blocking each other out?

Comment: Maybe you're isolating things *too much* and the query acquiring the lock ends up in a separate transaction, commits releasing the lock, then the subsequent operation that was supposed to rely on that lock being acquired runs again in a separate transaction and so on?

Comment: Is your code the only source of traffic on that db? Is it possible the difference is actually 3rd party interference, someone tinkering by hand, some other app interacting with it? Misconfigured test runs, accidentally hitting this db instead of the test db? You're not showing what you're doing or how you're doing it exactly, what results you're getting, what you wanted to get instead, or how you concluded the balances are wrong and why you think this is how they got wrong.